# Charged sphere shrinking

Tags: electromagnetism

I was solving a problem and it said that a "sphere which was uniformly charged was shrinking(with the radius as function of time), remaining this way as it shrinks". I could solve the problem, but I didn't understand this situation. I would like to know what could make the sphere shrink. That is, why is the sphere shrinking ? What are the possibilities ?

Comment: VTC unclear question and too broad a range of answers

Comment: Only one possibility exists. There is an external force on the sphere which is acting to compress the sphere. But that is obvious, and not the answer you wanted, right?

Comment: Repulsion between charges tends to expand the sphere, but some other force could cause shrinkage.  For example : (1) gravitational attraction, (2) elastic or surface tension forces if the sphere is a balloon or a soap bubble, (3) pressure difference between inner and outer atmosphere if again the sphere is a balloon or bubble.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a charged balloon, and you let the air slowly escape

Comment: I disagree. This is completely valid answer.

Comment: I also agree. Valid and satisfactory and straight to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to know where does the material go when it shrinks, right? Because it is hard to visualise a solid metal sphere shrinking while still retaining a perfectly spherical shape.

But its easier if you think about it the other way round.  Imagine a metal sphere being heated.  I think that it is now more intuitive that the sphere can retain its shape while growing bigger.  This is simply because the atoms in the solid are all getting more separated from one another.  Now if you cool the hot sphere back to its initial temperature it is believable that it can shrink back to a smaller radius while retaining its shape.

If this is still hard to visualise, you can think about how the shape of an inflated spherical balloon changes when you are taking air out of it.  It will retain a fairly spherical shape until it gets too deflated.